# Interface constants, Late Static Bindings

Tags: php, oop, interface, constants, late-static-binding

```
interface PasswordBrokerContract
{
    const PASSWORD_RESET = 'passwords.reset';

    public function reset(array $credentials, Closure $callback);
}

class PasswordBroker implements PasswordBrokerContract
{
    public function reset(array $credentials, Closure $callback)
    {
        // implementation

        return static::PASSWORD_RESET;
    }

}
```

Does it matter if you use `self` or `static` considering that interface constants can't be overridden by a class/interface that inherits them?

Comment: I guess, you can not override interface constant (but you can override class constant). After overriding you would get fatal error ```Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant ```

Comment: @yivi In a way that it will always be the same result no matter if you use `self` or `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could matter, because even if you can't override interface constants in classes implementing an interface, you can override these constants in classes *extending* the class that originally implemented the interface:

E.g. the following:

```
<?php

interface Contract
{
    const PASSWORD_RESET = 'passwords.reset';
    public function reset(): void;
}


class A implements Contract
{
    public function reset(): void
    {
        echo static::PASSWORD_RESET, "\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    const PASSWORD_RESET = 'foobar';
}
```

Now this:

```
(new A())->reset();
```

would output `passwords.reset`.

But this:

```
(new B())->reset();
```

would output `foobar`.

But if you didn't use late static binding, and used `self`, you'd get `passwords.reset` every time.

See it working [here](https://3v4l.org/YjLvn).

Comment: It's looks like a bug like this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73348